# jQuery plugin inside iframe; jQuery in parent window

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to get [jPlayer](http://www.jplayer.org/) to work inside an iframe. In an effort not to load jQuery twice, I'm using the following code in the iframe (to capture jQuery):

```
window.addEventListener("load", function (e) {

    if (typeof (jQuery) === "undefined")
    {
        // The body of the iframe.
        var context = document.body;

        jQuery = parent.jQuery;

        $ = function (selector) {
            return jQuery(selector, context);
        };
    }

    // Plugin is appended to the document here, to make sure jQuery is defined.
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = "/js/jquery.jplayer.min.js";
    document.head.appendChild(script);

    // Plugin stuff here..
    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({ /* ... settings ... */ });

});
```

I'm getting the following error at the line containing `$("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer()` :

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: You are loading plugin asynchronously here. You should try: `script.onload= function(){ $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({ /* ... settings ... */ });}; script.src = "/js/jquery.jplayer.min.js";`  But i'm really not sure this is your only issue here

Comment: This did away with the error. Now it's silently failing. Only if I include jQuery does it actually begin to play songs. Any ideas?

Comment: You have to provide MCVE, it could be just you are setting it incorrectly or anything else, who knows?!